# Referencing models.site in fixtures file used to populate multisite

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures

```
[
  {
    "model": "django.contrib.Site",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "domain_name": "en.localhost",
      "display_name": "EN site"
    }
  }]
```

I've made an app and put the fixture above in a directory name 'fixtures'.  When I run `python manage.py loaddata migrate/fixtures/sites_config.json`, I get the error:

> Problem installing fixture 'migrate/fixtures/sites_config.json': Invalid model identifier: 'django.contrib.Site'

- How do I reference the sites model in the fixture?
- Is this a sane strategy for configuring site in code (so i don't have to manually add sites in admin)
- Should I use the this strategy for managing a migration of content to a django site.  Ie, I create fixtures containing content for each content type and then I migrate them in before going live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sites.Site,

For the migration I went the way of fixtures and can't see any problems...